# Dell Inspiron 17R laptop no power

Tags: laptop, power, dell-inspiron

My friend asked me to fix his Dell Inspiron 17R, Reg Model P17E, DPN: D7T30 AOO, and unreadable service tag, which doesn't turn on, doesn't charge the battery, no nothin'.

Putting my ear to the case while repeatedly pressing the power button shows no sounds other than the power button press.  There's no whine, no fan, no HD, no speaker pop, absolutely nothing.

He tried a new power brick to no avail.  I've had it completely apart down the the motherboard being out of the case, and couldn't find anything obviously wrong with the mobo components, etc.  Re-seated the memory and wireless card already, too.

I checked 3 out of the 5 pins going to the PSU and there is power to be seen.  I should have checked the other 2.  This power jack is not attached to the mobo, but rather a cable, so it's easier to check and doesn't need to be re-soldered, even though the jack feels loose.

I've also purged "flea" power by removing the battery and PSU, then holding the power button for 30 sec.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be wrong with it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should edit your post to remove your distaste for Dell.  It puts some people off, and is not relevant to fixing the problem.   It sounds like the power regulation/supply circuitry in the laptop is failing.  It could also be a motherboard issue - When Intel produced a whole lot of bad laptop CPUs (a die issue) about 5 years ago, I had a number of laptops which just died as you described, and required a replacement motherboard.

Comment: This is an old enough laptop that I'm not going to recommend replacing the motherboard, but rather replacing the whole thing.  Thank you for the insight, but I'm hoping someone else has a different idea.  A bad mobo is the likely answer, though.  I just want to rule out something simpler first.